# How to show data in google map

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have a CSV file consists of thousand of data (columns are address1    address2    city    state    zipcode    tag    county    country) of some agents. I want to upload and show this data in google map .

Here is a reference:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_csv

I want to upload this CSV in C# by using this
like Bing Maps Customer Services where user can upload custom data and show in a bing map.

Comment: Surajit: please rewrite so there's a specific question.

Comment: What's your specific problem: uploading csv, geolocation, showing the map?

Comment: uploading csv is the main problem

Comment: @PHeiberg what happened to you????????????still you are not able to understand this question

Comment: Incredibly I got other stuff to attend to besides spending my day on SO. ;-) If you want faster answers, update your questions to be short and consise. In this case edit the question to say that you want to know how to upload (and possibly parse) the CSV. Put the google maps parts as separate questions.

Comment: @Surajit "How do I write a program" is often considered not a real question, as it is too general to get an answer of any merit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 POST http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/full
GData-Version: 2.0
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="authorization_token"
Content-Type: text/csv
Slug: A new map

name,latitude,longitude,description
Hello,-77.066395,-11.968312,Greetings from Lima!
There,145.34502,-38.51512,Out There Down Under
How,-88.421001,44.970465,How is Wisconsin?
Are,13.084501,63.399164,Sorry about that
You,140.637898,42.842568,I love you Hokkaido


    public static class ClientLogin
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Client login url where we'll post login data to.
        /// </summary>
        private static string clientLoginUrl = 
            @"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";

        /// <summary>
        /// Data to be sent with the post request.
        /// </summary>
        private static string postData = 
            @"service={0}&continue=http://www.google.com/&Email={1}&Passwd={2}&source={3}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Auth token you get after a successful login. 
        /// You'll need to reuse this token in the header of each new request you make.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service"></param>
        /// <param name="username"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetAuthToken(
            string service, string username, string password, string source)
        {
            // Get the response that needs to be parsed.
            string response = PostRequest(service, username, password, source);

            // Get auth token.
            string auth = ParseAuthToken(response);
            return auth;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse the Auth token from the response.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="response"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string ParseAuthToken(string response)
        {            
            // Get the auth token.
            string auth = "";
            try
            {
                auth = new Regex(@"Auth=(?<auth>\S+)").Match(response).Result("${auth}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new AuthTokenException(ex.Message);
            }

            // Validate token.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
            {
                throw new AuthTokenException("Missing or invalid 'Auth' token.");
            }

            // Use this token in the header of each new request.
            return auth;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a post request with all the login data. This will return something like:
        /// 
        /// SID=AQAAAH1234
        /// LSID=AQAAAH8AA5678
        /// Auth=AQAAAIAAAAB910
        /// 
        /// And we need the Auth token for each subsequent request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service"></param>
        /// <param name="email"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string PostRequest(
            string service, string email, string password, string source)
        {
            // Get the current post data and encode.
            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] encodedPostData = ascii.GetBytes(
                String.Format(postData, service, email, password, source));

            // Prepare request.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(clientLoginUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = encodedPostData.Length;

            // Write login info to the request.
            using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                newStream.Write(encodedPostData, 0, encodedPostData.Length);

            // Get the response that will contain the Auth token.
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                HttpWebResponse faultResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (faultResponse != null && faultResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    throw new IncorrectUsernameOrPasswordException(
                        faultResponse.StatusCode, faultResponse.StatusDescription);
                else
                    throw;
            }

            // Check for login failed.
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new LoginFailedException(
                    response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);

            // Read.
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

 string auth = ClientLogin.GetAuthToken("local", "username", "password", "");

UploadCSV(auth )

 public  string UploadCSV(string auth)
        {
            string URI = "http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/full";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
            //Add these, as we're doing a POST

            req.KeepAlive = false;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2.0");
            req.Headers.Add("Slug", "A new map");

            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:\\Surajit\\MapPoint\\1.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            req.ContentLength = fs.Length;
            req.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            WriteInputStreamToRequest(fs, outputStream);

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            outputStream.Close();
            fs.Close();
            if (resp == null) return null;
            StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }




protected void WriteInputStreamToRequest(Stream input, Stream output)
        {
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(output);
            const int size = 4096;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
            int numBytes;

            while ((numBytes = input.Read(bytes, 0, size)) > 0)
            {
                w.Write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
            }
            w.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: Hm, GetResponse() gets me a 503 error: "Service unavailable". How come?

Comment: might be some problem in your excel file.

Answer (score 2):

For uploading the csv file using webforms, see [Microsoft's tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246), but if you don't intend to save it physically I'd use a the stream directly from the upload control to avoid the need to save it to disk.

Parsing the csv could be made using any [csv parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx).

You can then show the data on a map using java script, using any of the [google maps api examples](http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/google-map-3-with-multiple-locations-in-asp-net-c/) on the web.

**Edit:** I managed to misunderstand your question despite your update. If you intend to call the rest services directly from c#, [this article](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET21) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/95842/Consuming-Google-Maps-API-Rest-Services-in-NET.aspx) might be helpful.

**Edit2:**
In order to send your csv data to the google api, you have to:

1. Authenticate and obtain an
   authentication token ([google
   documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#ClientLogin); [c#
   implementation](http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=XYC5KURLR7QC1RYH43FKF44LSH))
2. Make a post request containing your data and the authentication
   token you obtained in one ([example of how to send data via
   HttpPost](http://www.asp.net/QuickStart/howto/doc/WebRequests/clientPOST.aspx))

Comment: boss you have done a great mess....the data which will shown in map ......not 1 or 2...its thousands..so i want to to upload data by csv using google data api

Comment: pls read this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_csv

Comment: See my edit. You should be able to call the upload restful api for uploading your locations using an http request as made in the links I provided.

Comment: what is this?????????this is getting xml result by creating HttpWebRequest by using geogle geocoding just go by this url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Comment: @Surajit - It's the same method for sending your data. Disregard how the result is retrieved. It's the send part that's interesting in your case.

Comment: i don't need this.i need to upload data from csv file

Comment: thnx boss this links are helpful